# how can we store file with same name in capital and small letters in java

Tags: java, file, jaxb

I am creating a xml file using jaxb JAVA and xml file name given by user input using Jtextfield.when user is giving same name 2 times one in capital letters and another one in small letters its overidden the existing file how can we store file with same name in capital and small letters in java?

Comment: This is a function of your file system, not Java. If your file system is case insensitive, you cannot store two files whose names only differ in the casing of their letters within the same folder.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you can't.

File names are OS dependent.

The best you can do is provide a warning to the user that they are overwriting the same file.  See [File.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

The other solution is to always capitalise (or not) the first character

Comment: Also note on case insensitive file system, new `File("a").equals(new File("A"))` is `true`.

Comment: @unhillbilly You are right, I was thinking more a long the lines of expectations of the user, so the output is consistent, not that changing the character would make a difference to the problem - sorry, my bad for been unclear in my intentions

Comment: Hey ... you're fine.  I am not at all sure what UI behavior I would prefer on a case-insensitive system.  Warn on over-write?  Display all names in single case?  Generate extra chars (sequence number) in path name when saving?  I dunno.

Comment: @unhillbilly Yea for cross platform development ;)

Comment: @madProgrammer I have already done this.file is only store in lower case letter name.but is it a final soluation??

Comment: @user1618680 No, cause you'll still have the same problem you described (it was just only a suggest for consistency). I would do a `File.exists` check and warn the user that they may be overwriting the specified file. The other thing you can do is use a `DocumentFilter` on the text field that keeps the characters in lower case as the user types, but in reality, you still need to warn the user of the existing file

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Java issue, but a question for the underlying Operating System. Some allow you to create two files that only differ in capitalization (for example Linux), and some don't (Windows, for example).

There is nothing Java can do about it.